# How to display the number of Twitter followers (API v2) on my website?

Tags: php, api, curl, twitter

I used to display the Twitter followers count from a username (for example robbiewilliams) on my website but since API v2, it doesn't work anymore...

To solve this problem, I created a developer account on Twitter Developer Platform.
I created a Twitter application and configured the access keys and tokens needed to access the API.
Then, using PHP and cURL, I try to retrieve the data from my example account, but I get the following response:`Array ( [client_id] => 27054042 [detail] => When authenticating requests to the Twitter API v2 endpoints, you must use keys and tokens from a Twitter developer App that is attached to a Project. You can create a project via the developer portal. [registration_url] => https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/projects/overview [title] => Client Forbidden [required_enrollment] => Appropriate Level of API Access [reason] => client-not-enrolled [type] => https://api.twitter.com/2/problems/client-forbidden )`

I don't understand what is going wrong...

For this, I used the Twifer library and here is the code (of course I changed the passwords) :

```
<?php
session_start();
define('CONSUMER_KEY', '6arU1KnNsKSEsyQPPUkMHZLsG');
define('CONSUMER_SECRET', 'p6RoJ4nbQkjDZDnrhmD8sMKBUJWhPMpqmC78zokNpCzKezx3Sx');
define('OAUTH_TOKEN', 'Q3x0eDUwQ7JzX3dFN1hgZU1mkd98MTpjaQ');
define('OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET', 'cjucW1MLiOP9X7MPqjMPbuPBFuw1np7Eu7boTAktAHiaAFV_Ol');
define('OAUTH_CALLBACK', 'http://localhost:80/callback.php');
$bearerToken['access_token'] = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAANrPnAEAAAAKQJYd8OABv5%2FmblLscdrkHJovd7M%3D4FQFlsXgtstTZ0BGWxNpMPvP5JWiOTpAc7vD1ViGjyLHBGJ71S";

require 'src/API.php';
use Twifer\API;

$conn2 = new API(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $bearerToken['access_token']);
$res = $conn2->request('GET', 'users/by/username/robbiewilliams');
print_r($res);
?>
```

In the API.php file, I replaced `protected $apiStandardUrl = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/';` with `protected $apiStandardUrl = 'https://api.twitter.com/2/';`

I think I inserted the right tokens because if I change a single letter of the "Bearer" token, the result becomes : `Array ( [title] => Unauthorized [type] => about:blank [status] => 401 [detail] => Unauthorized )`
Thanks!

To complete my request: Twitter imposes, since a few months, the use of its API v2 which requires an authentication for each request. With v1, I could directly retrieve the number of followers of any account but it does not work anymore. I just want to display on my website the number of followers of each celebrity selected by a visitor.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Musk made this API endpoints paid.

In api v2 free tier you can access only to post tweets and GET `/2/users/me`.

For free, you can't get someone's following count unless they give you access via OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code with PKCE.

Comment: That would explain everything... Thank you very much.